# detect native prototypes vs extended prototypes

Tags: javascript

In some third party library, array prototype is extended:

```
Array.prototype.repeat = function(value, length) {
    while (length) this[--length] = value;
    return this;
};
```

code:

```
var model = {
  features:[1,2,3]
};


for (var p in model.features) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

Expect:

```
1
2
3
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
repeat
```

How can my code correctly determine properties that are beyond the normal prototype and skip them?

Comment: If the library does stuff you don't like, don't use it. However, there are several reasons to not use `for-in` on arrays in JS. This is just one.

Comment: Right. Don't use `for ... in` to iterate through arrays.

Comment: That `.repeat()` method is pretty questionable too. What if  a negative number is passed in? What library is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can iterate over an array in JavaScript. When choosing one you might want to consider following

- **browser support** (note that if you use a transpiler such as Babel then you are free to choose any)
- **efficiency** (although many modern browsers optimise for methods on `Array.prototype` they are still slower than a standard for loop).
- **readability** (it should be clear what the part of the code is responsible for, some of the patterns are more suitable than others for some cases)
- **immutability** (it has been observed that implicit changes in the state should be avoided, hence it is a good habit to use iterators that guarantee immutability of iterated array.)

From my own observations, I can tell that `Array.prototype.map()` is the preferable option by developers using transpilers, and paradigms of functional programming.

## For Loops

## `for..in`

Although it is **not recommended** to use `for..in` to iterate over arrays you can do so using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` as in following snippet.

```
for (const p in model.features) {
  if (model.features.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    console.log(model.features[p]);
  }
}
```

Results in

```
1
2
3
```

### `for..of`

However, you can use `for...of` instead which would be recommended when dealing with arrays.

```
for (const feature of model.features) {
  console.log(feature);
}
```

### `for`

This is your best bet if you do not use a transpiler and want to ensure that your code works on any browser.

```
for(var i = 0; i < model.features.length; i++) {
  console.log(model.features[i]);
}
```

## `Array.prototype`

There are also built-in methods on `Array.prototype` worth taking note of.

### `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
arr.forEach((value, index, array) => {

});
```

### `Array.prototype.map()`

```
arr.map((value, index, array) => {

});
```

Comment: Now it's even slower and needlessly verbose.

Comment: What about `.forEach()`?

Comment: it's worth noting that `for...of` doesnt work in IE. I ultimately did what I wanted using `.forEach()` but it's also as verbose as checking for `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: If you want to have best support possible you should use usual for loop. There are many ways in which you can iterate over an array including `for`, `map`, `for..of`, and `forEach`. I have given these examples since that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code at Question you can use `for` or `for..of` loop to iterate the array

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `.hasOwnProperty`
See working code here-> https://jsfiddle.net/xbdd6q13/2/

Or You can also use `for..of` instead of `for..in`

```
for (var p of model.features) {
                console.log(p);    
}
```